# "The immobility of countenance of a red Indian"

Tags: meaning, pop-culture

There is a sentence in [*The Naval Treaty*](http://www.freeenglish.jp/holmes/en/nava-en-013.html) (one case included in *The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes* by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle):

> He had, when he so willed it, the utter immobility of countenance of a red Indian, and I could not gather from his appearance whether he was satisfied or not with the position of the case.

What does this sentence mean?

In addition to the definitions of the individual words, I feel a cultural reference is being made here as well. What did Watson (or rather, Doyle) mean by this sentence?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: not mine, but I'd guess the stereotype insulted someone. Also the label "red Indian".

Comment: I've just added *my* downvote, and it's nothing to do with qualms over the term "Red Indian". I just think firstly it's common knowledge that Amerindian chiefs (along with poker players and Chinese politicians) are stereotypically associated with impassive faces. And secondly that the context makes it blindingly obvious even if you *didn't* already know this.

Comment: Litcrit is clearly off topic on ELU. And this *is* litcrit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it may fall under common knowledge for those aged 45 and upwards but nowadays the "Cowboy and Indian" film genre, so beloved between the 1950s and 1970s, is now very dated. Young European folk don't really know  how (N. American) Indians (i.e. Native Americans) were portrayed in the past.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Precisely *why* the "racial sterotype" emerged in the first place is Off Topic anthropology/sociology/history. And the matter of whether Conan Doyle *intended to convey/endorse* any of those possible reasons (as opposed to simply repeating an established cliche of his day) is Off Topic Lit Crit. And as to younger people not being familiar with the stereotype, I assume that means you've not seen Johnny Depp's ***Tonto*** in  [*The Lone Ranger*, 2013](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1210819/). Trust me, it's much the same as it ever was (except Depp's Tonto is fairly *smart!* :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Red Indian" is an old-fashioned, politically incorrect term for a Native American. One stereotype of Native Americans is that they're very stoic, possibly due to Edward Curtis's series of photographs of Native Americans with stern, serious expressions. (Of course, it's thought now that Curtis posed them in stereotypical ways to achieve the effect he wanted.)

So saying someone has the immobility of countenance of an Indian means that his face is still; he's not showing any emotion, like a stereotypical Native American.

Comment: Just call them Indians: they themselves do so, and who are we to tell them how they call themselves?

Comment: Some of them do; some of them don't. There are hundreds of different tribes, so naturally opinions differ.

Comment: Most ethnic groups despise being stereotyped into any homogenized quality description--including what they prefer to be called :-)

Comment: I believe Red Indian is a term more commonly found in the UK, or at least was at one time.  I am thinking of Peter Pan, for example.